# How to get interval value between two hours in mysql?

Tags: mysql, php

I want to get value between 2 hours:

```
11:30:00 => 245.90
10:30:00 => 215.80
11:30:00 - 10:30:00 => 245.90 - 215.80 = 30.1
```

and update data every hour.

**UPDATE**

I tried like this but didn't work

```
SELECT(SELECT kwh FROM energy_logger WHERE DATE = '$current_date' AND HOUR(Time) = '$cur_time' - SELECT kwh FROM energy_logger WHERE DATE = '$current_date' AND HOUR(Time) = '$last_time') as kwh_avg
```

**UPDATE1**

This is my table

[image]

**UPDATE2**

I want to do subtraction between 12:36:01 - 11:36:01 and put it to my graph

Comment: One reaseon why this may go wrong: you are comparing dates and numbers to strings.  One reason why this does go wrong: your selection returns multiple rows for a given hour.  Also very important: use a prepared statement with bind variables.

Comment: thank you sir, its very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most immediate reason your attempt did not work was because it was syntactically invalid.

You can use the result of a `SELECT` statement as a scalar value in an expression but you must enclose the said `SELECT` statement in parentheses. In your case, there are two such `SELECT` statements. Below is your attempted query slightly reformatted for readability with added comments to mark both of the SELECTs:

```
SELECT
  (
    /* this is SELECT #1 */
    SELECT kwh FROM energy_logger WHERE DATE = '$current_date' AND HOUR(Time) = '$cur_time'
    -
    /* this is SELECT #2 */
    SELECT kwh FROM energy_logger WHERE DATE = '$current_date' AND HOUR(Time) = '$last_time'
  ) as kwh_avg
```

Both SELECT #1 and SELECT #2 must be enclosed in parentheses *individually*, like this:

```
SELECT
  (
    /* SELECT #1 bracketed */
    (SELECT kwh FROM energy_logger WHERE DATE = '$current_date' AND HOUR(Time) = '$cur_time')
    -
    /* SELECT #2 bracketed */
    (SELECT kwh FROM energy_logger WHERE DATE = '$current_date' AND HOUR(Time) = '$last_time')
  ) as kwh_avg
```

The parentheses around the entire expression are not necessary, but they are not harmful or invalid either and may actually help readability.

The syntactic issue is now out of the way, but given the nature of your data, the query would still not work. It would produce an error of a different kind, and here is why. A `SELECT` statement can be used in a scalar expression like that only if it returns no more than one value. It means, the statement must

- select only one column, which is what you are doing correctly there,
  and
- return no more than one row, and that is where the issue is.

Based on your data sample screenshot, the filter condition in each of the subqueries,

```
WHERE DATE = ... AND HOUR(Time) = ...
```

can produce more than one row, because there can be many rows having the same `DATE` and `HOUR(Time)`. Therefore, those subqueries will simply fail to evaluate. You must ensure that each subquery returns one row *at most*. There might be more than one solution to that but this issue is out of the scope of the current question. Feel free to post a new question if you are struggling to resolve it on your own.

Comment: thank you sir, its very helpful